# clip-path property on div makes div's z-index higher then my fixed navbars

Tags: html, css, clip-path

```js
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
  sr.reveal('.b1', {
   duration: 2000,
   origin: 'top',
   distance: '80px'
  });
  sr.reveal('.b2', {
   duration: 1500,
   origin: 'top',
   distance: '80px'
  })
  sr.reveal('.b3', {
   duration: 1000,
   origin: 'top',
   distance: '80px'
  });
  sr.reveal('.w1', {
   duration: 3000,
   origin: 'right',
   distance: '200px'
  });
  sr.reveal('.w2', {
   duration: 3500,
   origin: 'right',
   distance: '150px'
  });
  sr.reveal('.w3', {
   duration: 4000,
   origin: 'right',
   distance: '150px'
  });
  sr.reveal('.h2-about', {
   duration: 2000,
   origin: 'top',
   distance: '150px'
  });


  const navBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-bars');
  navBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   const b1 = document.querySelector('.b1');
   const b2 = document.querySelector('.b2');
   const b3 = document.querySelector('.b3');

   addAnimation(b1);
   addAnimation(b2);
   addAnimation(b3);

   function addAnimation(bar) {
    bar.style.animationName = bar.className + '-animate';
   }
  });

  const aboutDiv = document.querySelector('.about-us');
  aboutDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
   const line = document.querySelector('.underline');
   line.style.animationName = 'line';
  })
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.side-menu {
 position: fixed;
 top: 140px;
 background-color: white;
 width: 299.5px;
 padding: 10px;
 transition: all 2s ease;
 left: -500px;
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.side-menu ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.side-menu li {
 color: grey;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 margin: 6px;
 margin-left: -35px;
 margin-bottom: 35px;
 font-family: 'Ubuntu';
}

.side-menu li:hover {
 color: orange;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-bars{
 position: fixed;
 left: 50px;
 top: 80px;
}

.b1, .b2, .b3 {
 width: 60px;
 height: 7px;
 background-color: red;
 margin:.55rem;
 border-radius: 9px;
}

.b1 {
 background-color: lightgreen;
 animation-duration: 3s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.b2 {
 background-color: white;
 animation-duration: 3s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.b3 {
 background-color: #ff4d4d;
 animation-duration: 3s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes b1-animate {
 from {}
 to {width: 60px; height: 8px; position: relative; left: -50px; top: 41px; width: 100px; border-radius: 0; background-color: lightgreen;}
}

@keyframes b2-animate {
 from {}
 to {width: 60px;
 height: 8px;
 position: relative;
 left: 35px; 
 top: 33px; 
 width: 150px; 
 height: 8px; 
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: white;}
}

@keyframes b3-animate {
 from {}
 to {width: 60px;
 height: 8px;
 position: relative;
 top: 25px;
 right: -169px; 
 width: 100px; 
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: #ff4d4d;}
}

.intro {
 background: lightblue;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 position: absolute;
 left: 700px;
 top: 50px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 3rem;
}

h2 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 font-size: 3rem;
 padding: 30px;
 color: white;
}

.about-us {
 margin-top: -40px;
 padding-bottom: 90px;
 background-color: #339966;
 width: 100vw;
}

.underline {
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 left: 570px;
 bottom: -120px;
 background-color: orange;
 width: 0px;
 height: 3px;
 animation-duration: 0.7s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

@keyframes line {
 from {left: 370px; width: 0px;}
 to {left: 570px; width: 210px; border-radius: 1.5px;}
}

p {
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 20px;
 top: -30px;
 color : white;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 word-spacing: 7px;
 width: 400px;
 font-family: 'Josefin sans';
 margin-left: 130px;
}
.fa-caret-down {
 position: relative;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 font-size: 60px;
 color: white;
 left: 665px;
 bottom: 300px;
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.image-slider {
 background-color: darkgrey;
 position: relative;
 width: 440px;
 height: 350px;
 right: -710px;
 bottom: 500px;
}


.right {
 position: relative;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 font-size: 60px;
 color: white;
 left: 1145px;
 bottom: 715px;
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.side-msg {
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 font-size: 3rem;
 color:#e6ac00;
 position: relative;
 right: -700px;
 font-weight: bold;
 top: -560px;
}

.chile {
 width: 460px;
 height: 345px;
 position: relative;
 top: -500px;
 z-index: 11;
}

.menu-wrapper {
 width: 100VW;
 background-color: #e6ac00;
 height: 905px;
 position: relative;
 top: -720px;
 clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 15%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>El Metate | Mexican food</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <nav>
   <div class="side-menu">
    <ul>
     <li>Home</li>
     <li>About</li>
     <li>Menu</li>
     <li>Contact</li>
     <li>Location</li>
     <li>News</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="menu-bars">
    <div class="b1"></div>
    <div class="b2"></div>
    <div class="b3"></div>
   </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="intro">
   <h1><span class="w1">Authentic</span><span class="w2">Mexican</span><span class="w3">Food</span></h1>
      <img src="" alt="">
  </div>
 </header>

 <section class="about">
  <div class="about-us">
   <h2 class="h2-about">About Us</h2>
   <div class="underline"></div>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat est ab adipisci illo consectetur obcaecati, incidunt, nesciunt ad vitae possimus nam inventore esse impedit. Ullam soluta architecto eligendi sapiente recusandae labore necessitatibus quis similique laboriosam quas, nam explicabo numquam commodi magni mollitia itaque hic quaerat earum, nemo optio maiores in.</p>
   <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
   <div class="image-slider">p</div>
   <i class="fas fa-caret-down right"></i>
   <p class="side-msg">Bueno Comida</p>
  </div> 
 </section>
 
 <section class="menu">
  <div class="menu-wrapper"></div>
 </section>

 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey Guy's I'm working on a website for this Mexican restaurant. At the moment, I just created a menu section colored in orange, I want to place it below the About us section. I want the top part of the menu section to be slanted. I did this using clip-path: polygon() on the menu div. The problem though is my nav bars are fixed in the upper left corner and whilst scrolling down to the menu section they slide below the div, as if the menu div has a higher z-index.
   Which was the first thing I tried and didn't work. I appreciate any help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the `z-index` of the fixed elements of the menu

```
.menu-bars{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50px;
    top: 80px;
    z-index:1; /*added this*/
}
```

Full code

```js
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
sr.reveal('.b1', {
  duration: 2000,
  origin: 'top',
  distance: '80px'
});
sr.reveal('.b2', {
  duration: 1500,
  origin: 'top',
  distance: '80px'
})
sr.reveal('.b3', {
  duration: 1000,
  origin: 'top',
  distance: '80px'
});
sr.reveal('.w1', {
  duration: 3000,
  origin: 'right',
  distance: '200px'
});
sr.reveal('.w2', {
  duration: 3500,
  origin: 'right',
  distance: '150px'
});
sr.reveal('.w3', {
  duration: 4000,
  origin: 'right',
  distance: '150px'
});
sr.reveal('.h2-about', {
  duration: 2000,
  origin: 'top',
  distance: '150px'
});


const navBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-bars');
navBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const b1 = document.querySelector('.b1');
  const b2 = document.querySelector('.b2');
  const b3 = document.querySelector('.b3');

  addAnimation(b1);
  addAnimation(b2);
  addAnimation(b3);

  function addAnimation(bar) {
    bar.style.animationName = bar.className + '-animate';
  }
});

const aboutDiv = document.querySelector('.about-us');
aboutDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  const line = document.querySelector('.underline');
  line.style.animationName = 'line';
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.side-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 140px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 299.5px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  left: -500px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.side-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.side-menu li {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin: 6px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
}

.side-menu li:hover {
  color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-bars {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.b1,
.b2,
.b3 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: .55rem;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.b1 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.b2 {
  background-color: white;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.b3 {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes b1-animate {
  from {}
  to {
    width: 60px;
    height: 8px;
    position: relative;
    left: -50px;
    top: 41px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}

@keyframes b2-animate {
  from {}
  to {
    width: 60px;
    height: 8px;
    position: relative;
    left: 35px;
    top: 33px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: white;
  }
}

@keyframes b3-animate {
  from {}
  to {
    width: 60px;
    height: 8px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    right: -169px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
  }
}

.intro {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
  position: absolute;
  left: 700px;
  top: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.about-us {
  margin-top: -40px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
  background-color: #339966;
  width: 100vw;
}

.underline {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 570px;
  bottom: -120px;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 0px;
  height: 3px;
  animation-duration: 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

@keyframes line {
  from {
    left: 370px;
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 570px;
    width: 210px;
    border-radius: 1.5px;
  }
}

p {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  top: -30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  word-spacing: 7px;
  width: 400px;
  font-family: 'Josefin sans';
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.fa-caret-down {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  left: 665px;
  bottom: 300px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.image-slider {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  position: relative;
  width: 440px;
  height: 350px;
  right: -710px;
  bottom: 500px;
}

.right {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  left: 1145px;
  bottom: 715px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.side-msg {
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #e6ac00;
  position: relative;
  right: -700px;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: -560px;
}

.chile {
  width: 460px;
  height: 345px;
  position: relative;
  top: -500px;
  z-index: 11;
}

.menu-wrapper {
  width: 100VW;
  background-color: #e6ac00;
  height: 905px;
  position: relative;
  top: -720px;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 15%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>El Metate | Mexican food</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="side-menu">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Menu</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
          <li>Location</li>
          <li>News</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-bars">
        <div class="b1"></div>
        <div class="b2"></div>
        <div class="b3"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="intro">
      <h1><span class="w1">Authentic</span><span class="w2">Mexican</span><span class="w3">Food</span></h1>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="about">
    <div class="about-us">
      <h2 class="h2-about">About Us</h2>
      <div class="underline"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat est ab adipisci illo consectetur obcaecati, incidunt, nesciunt ad vitae possimus nam inventore esse impedit. Ullam soluta architecto eligendi sapiente recusandae labore necessitatibus
        quis similique laboriosam quas, nam explicabo numquam commodi magni mollitia itaque hic quaerat earum, nemo optio maiores in.</p>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
      <div class="image-slider">p</div>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down right"></i>
      <p class="side-msg">Bueno Comida</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="menu">
    <div class="menu-wrapper"></div>
  </section>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can also replace `clip-path` with gradient and you will have better support:

```js
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
sr.reveal('.b1', {
  duration: 2000,
  origin: 'top',
  distance: '80px'
});
sr.reveal('.b2', {
  duration: 1500,
  origin: 'top',
  distance: '80px'
})
sr.reveal('.b3', {
  duration: 1000,
  origin: 'top',
  distance: '80px'
});
sr.reveal('.w1', {
  duration: 3000,
  origin: 'right',
  distance: '200px'
});
sr.reveal('.w2', {
  duration: 3500,
  origin: 'right',
  distance: '150px'
});
sr.reveal('.w3', {
  duration: 4000,
  origin: 'right',
  distance: '150px'
});
sr.reveal('.h2-about', {
  duration: 2000,
  origin: 'top',
  distance: '150px'
});


const navBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-bars');
navBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const b1 = document.querySelector('.b1');
  const b2 = document.querySelector('.b2');
  const b3 = document.querySelector('.b3');

  addAnimation(b1);
  addAnimation(b2);
  addAnimation(b3);

  function addAnimation(bar) {
    bar.style.animationName = bar.className + '-animate';
  }
});

const aboutDiv = document.querySelector('.about-us');
aboutDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  const line = document.querySelector('.underline');
  line.style.animationName = 'line';
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.side-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 140px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 299.5px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  left: -500px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.side-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.side-menu li {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin: 6px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
}

.side-menu li:hover {
  color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-bars {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.b1,
.b2,
.b3 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: .55rem;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.b1 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.b2 {
  background-color: white;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.b3 {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes b1-animate {
  from {}
  to {
    width: 60px;
    height: 8px;
    position: relative;
    left: -50px;
    top: 41px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}

@keyframes b2-animate {
  from {}
  to {
    width: 60px;
    height: 8px;
    position: relative;
    left: 35px;
    top: 33px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: white;
  }
}

@keyframes b3-animate {
  from {}
  to {
    width: 60px;
    height: 8px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    right: -169px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
  }
}

.intro {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
  position: absolute;
  left: 700px;
  top: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.about-us {
  margin-top: -40px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
  background-color: #339966;
  width: 100vw;
}

.underline {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 570px;
  bottom: -120px;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 0px;
  height: 3px;
  animation-duration: 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

@keyframes line {
  from {
    left: 370px;
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 570px;
    width: 210px;
    border-radius: 1.5px;
  }
}

p {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  top: -30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  word-spacing: 7px;
  width: 400px;
  font-family: 'Josefin sans';
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.fa-caret-down {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  left: 665px;
  bottom: 300px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.image-slider {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  position: relative;
  width: 440px;
  height: 350px;
  right: -710px;
  bottom: 500px;
}

.right {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  left: 1145px;
  bottom: 715px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.side-msg {
  font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #e6ac00;
  position: relative;
  right: -700px;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: -560px;
}

.chile {
  width: 460px;
  height: 345px;
  position: relative;
  top: -500px;
  z-index: 11;
}

.menu-wrapper {
  width: 100VW;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to top right, #e6ac00 49.8%,transparent 50%) top/100% 15.2% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#e6ac00,#e6ac00) bottom/100% 85% no-repeat;
  height: 905px;
  position: relative;
  top: -720px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>El Metate | Mexican food</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="side-menu">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Menu</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
          <li>Location</li>
          <li>News</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-bars">
        <div class="b1"></div>
        <div class="b2"></div>
        <div class="b3"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="intro">
      <h1><span class="w1">Authentic</span><span class="w2">Mexican</span><span class="w3">Food</span></h1>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="about">
    <div class="about-us">
      <h2 class="h2-about">About Us</h2>
      <div class="underline"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat est ab adipisci illo consectetur obcaecati, incidunt, nesciunt ad vitae possimus nam inventore esse impedit. Ullam soluta architecto eligendi sapiente recusandae labore necessitatibus
        quis similique laboriosam quas, nam explicabo numquam commodi magni mollitia itaque hic quaerat earum, nemo optio maiores in.</p>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
      <div class="image-slider">p</div>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down right"></i>
      <p class="side-msg">Bueno Comida</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="menu">
    <div class="menu-wrapper"></div>
  </section>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```